# Summary of "Large p, Small n" results

Tags: regression, classification, multivariate-analysis

Can anybody point me to a survey paper on "Large $p$, Small $n$" results?  I am interested in how this problem manifests itself in different research contexts, *e.g.* regression, classification, Hotelling's test, *etc*.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of a single paper, but I think the current book with the best survey of methods applicable to $p\gg n$ is still Friedman-Hastie-Tibshirani. It is very partial to shrinkage and lasso (I know from a common acquaintance that Vapnik was upset at the first edition of the book), but covers almost all common shrinkage methods and shows their connection to Boosting. Talking of Boosting, the [survey of Buhlmann & Hothorn](ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/Research-Reports/Other-Manuscripts/buhlmann/STS242.pdf) also shows the connection to shrinkage.

My impression is that, while classification and regression can be analyzed using the same theoretical framework, testing for high-dimensional data is different, since it's not used in conjunction with model selection procedures, but rather focuses on family-wise error rates. Not so sure about the best surveys there. Brad Efron has a ton of papers/surveys/book on [his page](http://stat.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/papers/). Read them all and let me know the one I should really read...

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "result" theoretical result ? or numerical results ?

I like the reviews of [Jianqing Fan](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/) see for example [this one](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1659322) and [this one](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/09/VSO1.pdf) on classification (lot of self citations).

Also there are non review paper that make rich review in introduction, see for example  [this one](http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/tsybakov/BRT_LassoDan.pdf) and [this one](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/45/68/06/PDF/HAL_EWA_LMC.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a resume maybe this is the best you can get

http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-3-642-20191-2

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 18 of [Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12.pdf) (12th printing/second edition, this chapter wasn't in the first edition) is a nice overview with some interesting data sets. It's not quite as thorough as their treatment of older material, and a lot of the time they have to give somewhat heuristic explanations of why certain algorithms work better than others. I found it very useful coupled with reading papers for things you want to know more in-depth.